# Volume stuck in music player - number changes, but doesn't affect actual volume

Tags: volume, xbox-music

When using the XBox music player, sometimes the volume hangs. In such cases, when I click the volume up/down I see the volume number increase/decrease, but it doesn't affect the actual volume - music/video always plays at exactly the same volume, whether I set the volume down to 0 or all the way up to 30.

- I haven't been able to pinpoint when this happens
- Switching between music and video (inside XBox) does matter - at that state, both music and video volume is stuck. FM Radio is not affected.
- Restarting the phone fixes the problem - until next time it happens...
- [Additional anecdotal evidence from a customer review](http://www.zap.co.il/ratemodel.aspx?modelid=835959) (translated from Hebrew): Player sometimes gets stuck on low volume and requires a restart.
- Phone: Lumia 920, using included earphones.

*(OS version 8.0.10328.78)* It appears that once in this state, the volume at turn-on time does take effect:

1. Suppose music is playing at volume 10.
2. You increase volume to 20 - you see "20", but music still plays at 10.
3. You change to a different song/video - still plays at 10.
4. Turn phone off/on (not restart, just off/on). Still plays at 10.
5. Play a different song/video - now it plays at 20!
6. Increase volume to 30 - you see "30", but music still plays at 20.

*(OS version 8.0.10517.150)* Above workaround works, and you don't need to turn phone off/on.

Comment: I have had this happen both with a developer Lumia 920, as well as a 520. It appears to happen at random.

Comment: I've experienced same. On that time I just change the music player. And I found that if you play a video at the same time, no issues .

Comment: I've experienced this too, on a Nokia 810.

Comment: This happens to me when I've been connected to a Bluetooth device. Killing the music app usually fixes it.

Comment: It happens to me also when I'm using headset, when it happens, i just remove my headset's jack and pull it again. The problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue as well, but restarting the phone solved it.

Comment: I would not say that this "solves" the problem. It temporarily allows you to adjust the volume again, but this volume freezing issue will most likely happen again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because you are playing a video and then stopping it while the volume is low, as described in [this forum post](http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-810/233686-low-volume-xbox-music.html)

Comment: Nope, video doesn't change. See added research in edit in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a bug.
It happens to me(Lumia 525) also when I'm using headset, when it happens, i just remove my headset's jack and connect it again. The problem will be solved